# Bash script for Ghost blog not starting up on server reboot

Tags: node.js, bash, cron, forever, ghost-blog

I have a very simple bash script which should launch my ghost blog. I am using `crontab` to launch the script on startup, here is the crontab command I am running:

```
@reboot /var/www/ghost/launch.sh
```

The script has the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

ps auxw | grep apache2 | grep -v grep > /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
        NODE_ENV=production forever start --sourceDir /var/www/ghost index.js
fi
```

When I `sudo reboot` the server, and use `forever list` to find the processes running, I see the following:

```
data:    [0] sHyo /usr/bin/nodejs index.js 1299    1314 /home/webadmin/.forever/sHyo.log 0:0:1:25.957
```

When I `nano` to that log file, the log says the following:

```
^[[31m
ERROR:^[[39m ^[[31mCould not locate a configuration file.^[[39m
^[[37m/home/webadmin^[[39m
^[[32mPlease check your deployment for config.js or config.example.js.^[[39m

Error: Could not locate a configuration file.
    at checkTemplate (/var/www/ghost/core/config-loader.js:16:36)
    at Object.cb [as oncomplete] (fs.js:168:19)

error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: null
```

It appears to be looking in `/home/webadmin/`, but ghost is installed at `/var/www/ghost`????

When I run the exact same script in the terminal manually after the sever has started up by `ssh`-ing into the server, the script works fine. I run: `cd /var/www/ghost/` and then `./launch.sh` and the ghost blog appears and is working fine. The log for that `forever` process says the following:

```
^[[32mGhost is running...^[[39m
Your blog is now available on http://blog.example.com ^[[90m
Ctrl+C to shut down^[[39m
```

What is wrong with my script or crontab that it cannot launch the script properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I run: `cd /var/www/ghost/` and then `./launch.sh` and the ghost blog appears and is working fine.

That's the thing, your cron job is not doing the same:

```
@reboot /var/www/ghost/launch.sh
```

This script is executed from your home directory. One way to fix is to change your crontab:

```
@reboot cd /var/www/ghost; ./launch.sh
```

Another way is to add this line near the top of `launch.sh`, anywhere before launching `forever`:

```
# change to the directory of this script
cd $(dirname "$0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI for anybody that runs across this I would highly suggest looking into pm2 to start Ghost and to monitor Ghost.  It will monitor Ghost like Forever and has a built in feature to generate a init script to start pm2 when your server restarts.  Also has better features to monitor Ghost while it is running.  Check out my how to [here](http://www.allaboutghost.com/keep-ghost-running-with-pm2/).